# how to create the multiple instance of the android app

Tags: android

I searched various apps in the Google play which create multiple instances of an installed app in their workspace. I want to do the same in my app. I have researched and found that they rename the installed app's package name.

How can I rename my installed app package name?  I tired various ways but none of those work. Please help me to resolve this issue.

https://github.com/sjitech/ApkRename

http://www.guruswizard.com/2015/02/clone-any-android-app-apk-editor.html

Above are the links which I tired to rename the installed package.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Gradle for your builds you can use [Build Types](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#build-types) to generate different apk files with different package names.

Small example from the link:

```
buildTypes {
    versionA {
        applicationIdSuffix ".a"
    }

    versionB {
        applicationIdSuffix ".b"
    }
}
```

This will add '.a' and '.b' to your package names.

Comment: thanks chrish ...can u explain me how to do this  in real application or link for this .... but i want don't have the source code the app i have only the installed application in device